# Creating query which sorts and returns certain categories first

Tags: reactjs, react-native, elasticsearch

Let's say I have 3 categories: A, B, & C. I want A to be displayed first, then B, lastly C.

Certain categories have a boolean which would also give it a priority. Let's call that "isPriority". Let's assign "isPriority" to * for my example on the next line

So the order should be: A*, A, B*, B, C*, C.

I figured I could set a weight per category, and if `isPriority` is true, then multiply the weight. Here's my code:

```
 query: {
    function_score: {
      query: {
        match_all: {},
      },
      functions: [
        {
          filter: {
            match: {
              category: 'A',
            },
          },
          weight: 100,
        },
        {
          filter: {
            match: {
              category: 'B',
            },
          },
          weight: 90,
        },
        {
          filter: {
            match: {
              category: 'C',
            },
          },
          weight: 80,
        },
        {
          filter: {
            match: {
              isPriority: true,
            },
          },
          weight: 2,
        },
      ],
      score_mode: 'multiply',
    },
  },
};
```

YET, the results being returned are sort of in this order:

`B*, B*, B*, C*, C*, B*, A*, B*`

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of data for me to test on your logic?